# Am I safe executing this outside "document.ready()" block?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Would I be safe moving this piece of code out from inside the `document.ready()` block.

```
var $userInfoNode = $('#userOptions');
CURR_USER_ID = $userInfoNode.attr('data-userId');
CURR_USER_NAME = $userInfoNode.text();
```

This code is placed in an external js file that is loaded from the `head` section of html page &  selects an html element placed within html `body`, to extract data from there.

Comment: Only if that coded is placed in the document after the elements it refers to exists. What's wrong with keeping it in doc ready?

Comment: Will only work out of docready if is placed after the libraries (jquery in this case) AND after the element it refers to or $('#userOptions') will return undefined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Short answer:** No, since the JavaScript file is placed in the header.

The DOM (Document Object Model) needs to contain the `<div id="userOptions">` when the code is executed.

Either you place the code *after* the `div`, for example right before the closing `</body>`.

Or you place the code within the `$(document).ready()` function, which is triggered as soon as the DOM is fully loaded.

Comment: The OP says "This code is placed in an external js file that is loaded from the `head` section"

Comment: Thank you, I missed that. Then no.

Answer (score 2):

> - out of the document.ready() block.
> - external js file that is loaded from the head section
> - selects an html element placed within html body

=> No. You can try it and will find `$userInfoNode` empty.

Comment: @Blowsie But the OP says "This code is placed in an external js file that is loaded from the `head` section"

Comment: @Blowsie: The question explicitly states that the script is in `<head>` and the selected element is in `<body>`. Have you ever seen a head placed below a body?

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

You also need to ensure that the html elements you are going to refer to appear before your javascript.

in short put this

```
var $userInfoNode = $('#userOptions');
CURR_USER_ID = $userInfoNode.attr('data-userId');
CURR_USER_NAME = $userInfoNode.text();
```

at the end of your html page...

Comment: The OP says "This code is placed in an external js file that is loaded from the `head` section"

Answer (score 0):

If you have to/want to keep it in an external file you can place the script element that references it at the bottom before your closing body tag. It looks a little weird at first but it is valid.